# Is buffer pool shared per binding or per endpoint?

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding

When setting up WCF configuration for use on a client, is the `maxBufferPoolSize` capped per `binding` or is the pool created per `endpoint`?

Essentially, with a `bindings/basicHttpBinding` entry of:

```
<binding name="LargeBufferBinding" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00"
  receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" allowCookies="false"
  bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
  maxBufferPoolSize="4194304" maxBufferSize="4194304" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304"
  textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
  messageEncoding="Text">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="4194304" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
  <security mode="None">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
      realm="" />
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
  </security>
</binding>
```

And later, `client` entries of:

```
<endpoint address="..." binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeBufferBinding" contract="..." name="Svc1"/>
<endpoint address="..." binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeBufferBinding" contract="..." name="Svc2"/>
<endpoint address="..." binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeBufferBinding" contract="..." name="Svc3"/>
<endpoint address="..." binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeBufferBinding" contract="..." name="Svc4"/>
```

Is the client going to be capped to a buffer pool for those WCF services at 4MB or at 16MB?